# How to make an evil looking moon that runs naturally?

Tags: moons, gods

An omnipotent but not omniscient or omnibenevolent deity has decided that creating an evil looking moon that works according to natural law would be a great addition to their world's mythology.

[image: evil moon]

They want it to be as dramatic as possible, and their power budget is effectively infinite. Evil looking face, glowing eyes, anything that makes the moon look spooky and sinister. However, they're not sure how to make sure the moon keeps looking evil in the long run, even if they leave and go off to do other things.

They are not omniscient. They have immense knowledge and intelligence, but not perfect future prediction. While they can reshape the moon as desired, and do anything within the laws of physics, biology, or chemistry, creating some sort of endlessly lasting magical or technological construct or illusion that lasts forever is beyond them, as is a perfectly ordered intelligent civilization that will do exactly what they want to maintain a magical or technological construct forever. Ideal answers will rely on mostly natural causes for the spooky moon face, but will be durable enough to last a few thousand years without maintenance.

Comment: See the Jack Vance story "The Face": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Face_(Vance_novel)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Large impact craters will define the shape of eyes and evil grin. In the eyes the central rebound peak will even give you the pupil. For the grin in particular, you just need a stripe of suitably aligned craters. Our remarkable pareidolia will ensure that we will see a face there. [We already do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_in_the_Moon).

Then, to increase the dramatic effect, cover the areas you want to be red with generous amounts of iron oxide. Mars is known as the red planet for good reasons, it has been associated to war because of its bloody color.

For bonus evil appearance, you can set up cliffs that with certain angles of incidence will look like faces, sort of what happened with the famous face on Mars. That might help when the moon is not yet full and sunlight is more grazing.

Comment: I so much would prefer the sickly viridian green of the chromium (III) oxide to the iron oxide.

Comment: That's pretty interesting, that people already see a man on the moon. That would make it quite a bit easier.

Answer (score 7):

Just painting the Moon should last for a few millennia - just make sure to use UV resistant pigments.

Otherwise, mini-impactors creating craters of 0.1-1km radius (will show as a darker shadow, due to the direction in which the slopes of the crater will reflect the light) and using [dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither) to create the image. These are bound to last for millions of years at least.

Dithered, it may look like this (it'd be nicer with deeper black eye sockets, but it they can't be made black under all angles of illumination. Unless you paint them black, that is)

[image]

Comment: Layer on the paint a few meters high

Comment: @lidar why meters high? [Painting it red, then writing Coca Cola](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/fztsk0/comment/fn6p2jy/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) was allegedly one of the MAD era approaches.

Comment: @Adrian Colomitchi: I think that's a steal from Heinlein's "The Man Who Sold the Moon".  It wasn't that Harriman was actually planning to paint the moon, he was selling the idea that other companies (or the Soviets) wanted to, so your company should pay him for the rights to keep them from doing so.

Comment: @jamesqf Thanks for the ref, I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

**No Rounded features**

Big round eyes and round face are the signs that our instinct identify as belonging to children and trigger protective behaviour. They would not appear so threatening. So your moon should be smaller than the mass that would push an object to get a perfectly spheric shape, something like [Vesta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4_Vesta). In order to be visible it should orbit quite close to the planet.

For some geological reason the satellite is made by a bright reflective material covered by dark carbonaceous chondrites. Two obliquous impacts would exposte two narrow strips giving te appearence of narrow eyes.

With the other irregularities of the surface appearing as scars on a face you won't need a grin, those two eyes constantly staring from above would be threatening enough.

Comment: "Big round eyes and round face are the signs that our instinct identify as belonging to children and trigger protective behaviour." You'd feel like protecting little Johnny, don't you? Well... [Here's Johnny!](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0630/8509/products/pst1048_Shining_Heres_Johnny_Movie_Poster_grande.jpg?v=1621348639)

Comment: "Big round eyes and round face"?  So you feel really protective towards Jack O'Lanterns, do you?